# Xamarin app integration with native app

Tags: mobilepush-android

We are working on  a POC to integrate Xamarin app with SFMC mobile Push. Since SFMC Mobile push SDK is not available for Xamarin framework, we are following the binding approach to integrate Xamarin to native sdk code. With this approach, we will be able to call the SDK methods directly from the Xamarin code. Version of the Android MobilePush SDK we are using is 6.3.3.

Current Issue: With this binding approach, most of the notification related classes/interfaces/methods got parsed. However, we are facing issue with below 2 methods that are available in native SDK and are not getting parsed.

1. Class (NotificationManager) -> Interface (NotificationBuilder) ->  Method- setupNotificationBuilder(Context context, NotificationMessage notificationMessage)
2. Class (NotificationManager) -> Method - getDefaultNotificationBuilder(Context context, NotificationMessage notificationMessage, String paramString, int paramInt)

If anyone worked on this some guidance  it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I know we've corresponded in other channels, but adding my note here to help others.

Xamarin integrations are not supported by the MobilePush SDK team. Method binding is the responsibility of the application developer and any issues would be with the Xamarin tools or usage of them.

Brian
Senior Mobile Engineer & Product Owner, MobilePush SDK

Comment: Is official Xamarin support on the roadmap at all?